# Django admin panel makes unnecessary queries when memoizing related object in model __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, optimization, django-admin

**Django = 2.2**

**Python = 3.6**

I have two models named `Pl` and `Exam` in Django:

```py
class Pl(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pl = models.ForeignKey("Pl")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Exam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pl = self.pl
```

The ModelAdmin looks as follows.

```py
@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ """

    show_full_result_count = False
    list_display = ("id", "name")
    list_select_related = ("pl",)
```

As shown in the code, the `Exam` model's `__init__` method makes a query to the `Pl` model to memoize it. This is causing problems on the admin panel, where if I want to display 100 `Exam` objects on the list page, it makes 100 queries for each object.

I have tried using `list_select_related = ("pl", )`, but it didn't work.

I have also tried to override the `get_queryset` method in the admin panel and use `select_related("pl")`, but it still makes those queries.

To debug the issue, I updated the `__init__` method as follows:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Exam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(self._state.fields_cache) # name this print statement as "A"
    self._pl = self.pl
```

And then I tried the following query:

```py
exams = Exam.objects.all().select_related("pl")
exam = exams.last()
print(exam._state.fields_cache) # name this print statement as "B"
```

"B" always shows the cached field and returns `{'pl': <Pl: 1>}`, but "A" always returns an empty dictionary `{}` indicating that the `self` object doesn't have the cached object.

How can I memoize the related `Pl` object in the `Exam` model without triggering additional queries when accessing it, particularly in the Django admin panel?

Comment: Memoization will *not* work since the `QuerySet` will each time make new objects. Please undo these changes and share the `ModelAdmin`..

Comment: Based on the `ModelAdmin`, I don't see where the `p1` is used by the way?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Willem. I have updated the question and added the ModelAdmin as requested.

Regarding my original question, my main concern is understanding why the cached fields are unavailable in the `__init__` model method while available on the `exam` object.

I also checked the location of both the objects, `self` and `exam`, using `id()`, and they were the same.

Can you please help me understand why the cached fields are not available in the __init__ method of the model?

Comment: The `pl` and `_pl` attributes are not used in the `ModelAdmin` but in another part of the code. However, as it was memoized in the `__init__` method, it was causing a significant number of queries on the admin list page.

Comment: evidently: it means that each time youmake a single `Exam`, it will fetch the related `.pl`, so if you fetch 1'00 `Exam`s, it performs 1'00 `Pl` queries as well. You should identify where the N+1 problem is in the rest of the code, but *not* override the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

By your "memoize" constructor, you are making it worse: now it will *each* time when you fetch an `Exam`, make a query for that single `Exam` object to fetch its `.p1`. This is thus basically a pattern to make an *n+1* query for a *lot* of queries with `Exam`, even if these `Exam`s don't need a `.pl` at all.

```
@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    show_full_result_count = False
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    list_select_related = ('pl',)
```

and *without* overriding the `__init__` method (or at least not call `.pl` or any other `ForeignKey` field).

---

> **Note**: [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) is [no longer supported <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) since April 2022, you should consider upgrading the Django version.

Comment: In my code, I used `select_related` in the ModelAdmin to reduce the number of queries made to the database. Although I can see the cached fields in the `exam` object, they are not available on the `self` object in the `__init__` method, and I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: @Anup: as discussed in the answer because it *first* calls the constructor, and *then* sets the `.pl` attribute, so at the time of the constructor, it is *not* yet available.